# How to redirect all wordpress generated thumbnail images to the original ones

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I moved a `wordpress` website from a server to another and I need to save the disk space. So I've wrote a script that deletes all image generated files.

```
find . -name '*-[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9].*' | xargs rm -f
find . -name '*-[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].*' | xargs rm -f
find . -name '*-[0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*' | xargs rm -f
find . -name '*-[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9].*' | xargs rm -f
find . -name '*-[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].*' | xargs rm -f
find . -name '*-[0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*' | xargs rm -f
find . -name '*-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9].*' | xargs rm -f
find . -name '*-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9].*' | xargs rm -f
find . -name '*-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]x[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9].*' | xargs rm -f
```

I need to redirect all url requests for thumbnail images to the default image because it would be a dead link..

some examples

```
/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/image-200x200.png to /wp-content/uploads/2017/03/image.png
/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/image-20x1200.tiff to /wp-content/uploads/2018/12/image.tiff
/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/image-1900x300.png to /wp-content/uploads/2019/05/image.png
/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/image-30x30.gif to /wp-content/uploads/2019/05/image.gif
/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/image1-200x50.jpg to /wp-content/uploads/2019/05/image1.jpg
/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/imag2e-2010x2100.jpeg to /wp-content/uploads/2019/05/imag2e.jpeg
```

I need to do it with all the possible combinations on 4 digit length max of image resolution file name.

Is there any way to do it with .htaccess? or do you suggest something else via wordpress api or plugin?

I'm not an expert in mod_rewrite and rewrite conditions, I tried this one, but not working

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !/wp-content/*/*/.*
RewriteRule ^/wp-content/uploads/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/-([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)(.jpeg|.png|.jpg|.tiff|bmp)$ ^wp-content/uploads/$1/$2/-$5 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

For removing the dimension part from your URLs, you can use this regex,

```
(.*)-\d+[xX]\d+(\.\w+)
```

and replace it using `$1$2`

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oOQ0ac/1)**

Hence in WordPress redirect plugin, you will have to write something like this,

```
Source: (.*)-\d+[xX]\d+(\.\w+)
Target: $1$2
```

You may refer to **[this link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29147/redirection-plugin-redirect-all-urls-with-a-regular-expression)** for how to use redirection plugin and configure it. I'm not very familiar with WordPress redirection plugins but hoping this information helps in resolving your problem.

Comment: It works on local environment, but I get 404 page not found on server

Comment: How is your regexp using htaccess including all 404 images?

Comment: It doesn ‘t. Tried now. It seems that wp is not loaded. It’s a 404 error before the refirection. Or didn’t redirect correctly

Comment: Yes. I think it’s an Apache related problem here. The regex itself works